# Suggestion in putting nav bar in centred website design

Tags: website-design, gui-design, navigation

Can anyone suggest where I can add navigation bar in this kind of design.

items I want on the nav bar

1. logo (optional)
2. call to action button
3. one more link
4. user/profile/login/signup

Can anyone suggest or if refactor with the requirement will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Why not put a sticky nav bar on the top of the page, similar to the one here, on stackoverflow?

Comment: I recommend using a side-sticky navigation.